# Wildcard Pattern Matching in Naive string pattern matching

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-matching

i'm trying to add wildcard pattern matching in my simple naive string matching algorithm,especially the character "*" which will match one or more characters in my list of characters. I have one wildcard character, "?" , which will match one character, implemented. But i have difficulties implementing the "*" wildcard

First here's my simple algorithm:

pat is a list of character patterns

txt is a list of characters

```
 def search(pat,txt):
        M = len(pat)
        N = len(txt)
        
        for i in range(N-M+1):
            j=0
            while(j<M):
                if pat[j]=="?":
                    j+=1
                    continue
                if (txt[i+j]!=pat[j]):
                    break
                j+=1
                
    
            if(j==M):
                print("Pattern found at index ",str(i))

txt=["A","A","B","A","A","A","C","A","A","D","A","A","B","A","A","A","B","C","A"]
pat=["A","A","?","C"]
search(pat,txt)
# Pattern found at index  3
# Pattern found at index  14

txt=["A","A","B","A","A","A","C","A","A","D","A","A","B","A","A","A","B","C","A"]
pat=["A","A","B","C"]
search(pat,txt)
# Pattern found at index  14
```

what i want is this using some examples:

```
txt=["C","a","t","o","r","d","o","g","i","l","o","v","e","b","o","t","h"]
pat=["d","o","g","*","b","o","t","h"]
search(pat,txt)
# Pattern found at index  5
# Corresponding to ["d","o","g","i","l","o","v","e","b","o","t","h"]

txt=["C","a","t","o","r","d","o","g","i","l","o","v","e","b","o","t","h"]
pat=["i","*"]
search(pat,txt)
# Pattern found at index  8
# Corresponding to ["i","l","o","v","e","b","o","t","h"]

txt=["C","a","t","o","r","d","o","g","i","l","o","v","e","b","o","t","h"]
pat=["*","i"]
search(pat,txt)
# Pattern found at index  0
# Corresponding to ["C","a","t","o","r","d","o","g","i"]
```

How can i do this? Can someone help me please or atleast guide me to the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exercise is covered in depth at [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcard-pattern-matching/) and reading that resource carefully is probably your best bet. I'll give a quick TLDR here:

- Adding wildcard matching makes your coding task significantly more complicated. Depending on your experience level, it might be pretty hard to wrap your head around.
- The basic idea is to build an array `dp` such that `dp[j][k]` is `True` if the first `k` characters of the pattern form a valid match for the first `j` characters of the input string, and `False` otherwise.